# How to recursively source scripts (components) in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have started an AngularJS 1.6.x project a while ago and I am trying to organize it now in components. I have managed to do something acceptable with directives and templates. But in the end, I always have to include **all** my javascript in the *index.html*. So my *index.html* has become quite big.

My project looks like this, but with many many lines of `<script src=...`:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="component1/ctrl.js"></script>
    <script src="component1/subcomponent1/ctrl.js"></script>
    <!-- many lines here -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <component1></component1>
  </body>
</html>
```

**component1/ctrl.js**

```
//import subcomponent1 from './component1/subcomponent1/ctrl'; << I want something like this
app.directive('component1', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: "component1/view.html",
        scope: true
    }
});
```

**component1/view.html**

```
Here is component 1.
<subcomponent1></subcomponent1>
```

And so on with subcomponent1, component2, and the others...

How could I have my components recursively import just the other components they need? Ideally this should be done in the files *ctrl.js*.

Comment: you could add specific component js to its own template

Comment: How do you do that? Do you mean add `<script src=...` inside the **view.html**?

Comment: Or you can think about using bundling system. If you use webpack, grunt or gulp I think you can do it. It's a harder to implement but in general it's better approach if your application grows up in the future.

Comment: @Iaroslav - Thanks, I'm checking webpack. It seems it is what bundles are made for. So no pure javascript/html/angularjs solution? How would you write it with webpack anyway?

Comment: @RaphaMex If you don't use any package system it will take much effort to set up especially if you're not familiar with. But first, what do you use for back-end?

Comment: @Iaroslav I'm using nodejs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use webpack, bundle-js or any other bundling system. I would suggest webpack cause now it's the most popular module bundler. Since you're using nodejs it won't be so difficult.

Since it's pretty hard to explain all stuff here I'm applying a good guide to set up webpack.

https://medium.com/javascript-training/beginner-s-guide-to-webpack-b1f1a3638460

Here is bundle-js: https://gist.github.com/rstacruz/1ff36e7ce207aef513cea1c3a9e5400d